# "Drop" event not fire

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

This code is not work:

```
$('#dropbox').bind('drop', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    // more code
});
```

I tried to use "on" instead of "bind", but it does not work.
I am using Jquery and Jquery UI from [Google Hosted Libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to show some more code..A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) will be great

Comment: @MohammadAdil, the problem that the code, binded on drop event, is not executed

Comment: create a fiddle if possible...